# OCR PDF missing gaps in Firefox

Tags: pdf, ocr, tesseract, pdf.js

I have problem with searchable PDF created by tesseract. It is not generated, I do that by my own way in C++ project according to example on their Github - [pdfrenderer.cpp](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/src/api/pdfrenderer.cpp) 
But when I open the PDF document in Firefox, there is missing gaps between each words, in Chromium not. Does anyone know why? I could not find anything about it. I am working under Ubuntu 18.01 with tesseract v4 (I had same problem under ubuntu 17.xx with tesseract v3.x).

**Edit1:** example PDF - [Example PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lq9mwsV8QuzflQA7rdF2POH17hm4MURl)

Comment: It would be great if you could add some examples of the issue. I can't see your PDF documents. Also, the version of Firefox would be helpful.

Comment: @DanWilson I added example of PDF document and version of Firefox is 60.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: Best I can tell is that the PDF renderer in Firefox has [quite a few issues](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?resolution=---&query_format=advanced&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&component=PDF%20Viewer&product=Firefox).

Comment: There also are some issues in the PDF, though. E.g. the **ToUnicode** map of the font is invalid, its only `beginbfrange` entry is `<0000> <ffff> <0000>` which is not valid, at least not for PDF ToUnicode CMaps. Thus, tesseract also is to blame.

Comment: @mkl Thank you very much, I will focus on this part of pdf structure. Btw. could you recommend me some websites/books/tutorials, which are dealing with it?

Comment: *"I will focus on this part of pdf structure"* -  I don't claim that those issues cause the problem, so don't focus too much on them. *"Btw. could you recommend me some websites/books/tutorials, which are dealing with it?"* - [ISO 32000-1](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) already specifies restrictions of the CMap format for **ToUnicode** maps.